# Translation "나트륨의 과다 섭취가 각종 질환을 일으킬 수 있다는 인식이 확산 되고 있습니다"

Tags: meaning

Here is the sentence:

> 나트륨의 **과다** 섭취가 각종 질환을 일으킬 수 **있다는** 인식이 확산 되고 있습니다

The sentence is difficult for me to undertand because i'm not sure about the meaning of "과다" and "있다는". "과다" is "과다가", and "있다는" is "있는", right? Can you help me to understand this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"과다 = excessive" should be in any Korean dictionary.

과다 섭취 = excessive consumption

있다는: -다는 is a verb suffix used to quote another sentence ([...] below).

> [나트륨의 과다 섭취가 각종 질환을 일으킬 수 있다는] 인식이 확산되고 있습니다.
>
> = The notion [that too much consumption of sodium can cause various health conditions] is becoming widespread.