# Translation "칭찬을 들으면 .... 생기게 된다"

Tags: meaning

Can you help me to translate this sentence into English:
"칭찬을 들으면 그 기대에 부응해야 한다는 압박감 떄문에 자신의 실력을 제대로 발휘자지 못하게 되는 일이 생기게 된다".

Comment: Can you tell us why you need this sentence translated into English and what the most difficult part is based on your own research? This site is not a translation service site. Sorry for the downvote.

Comment: It would definitely be good if you could point out the parts you're finding difficult, as you did here: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/translation-%eb%82%98%ed%8a%b8%eb%a5%a8%ec%9d%98-%ea%b3%bc%eb%8b%a4-%ec%84%ad%ec%b7%a8%ea%b0%80-%ea%b0%81%ec%a2%85-%ec%a7%88%ed%99%98%ec%9d%84-%ec%9d%bc%ec%9c%bc%ed%82%ac-%ec%88%98-%ec%9e%88%eb%8b%a4%eb%8a%94-%ec%9d%b8%ec%8b%9d%ec%9d%b4-%ed%99%95%ec%82%b0-%eb%90%98%ea%b3%a0-%ec%9e%88%ec%8a%b5%eb%8b%88%eb%8b%a4 - that makes it much easier for someone to put some explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basically means when you get complimented by someone you perform less because you pressurize your self to meet the expectation

Comment: When ones gets complimented by someone, one sometimes perform less because of the pressure to meet the expectation.